# How to get the text from a particular xpath and how to store that in a string using Serenity

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

I want to fetch the text from an xpath and store it in a string.

After entering all inputs and submitting , a new code will get generated and which looks like Customercode: IN02732114(number will dynamic).

Now i want to fetch this code and store it in a string and later I want to use this string in other steps to search the data with this code.

i have used below different snippets to get the text from the xpath.

public static Question customer_code_value() {
return actor -> Text.of(CustomerCreatePage.CUSTOMER_CODE_TEXT).viewedBy(actor).asString().substring(15, 26);
}

String code= customer_code_value(); // trying to store the value in String code

but customer_code_value() method returns in Question and cant store in String.

Need some help on how to get the text and store it in string in Serenity.
Please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

To locate an element, use the [`Target`](https://serenity-js.org/modules/protractor/class/src/screenplay/questions/targets/Target.ts%7ETarget.html):

```js
import { Target } from '@serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protractor';

class CustomerCreatePage {
    static customerCode = () =>
        Target.the('customer code').located(by.xpath(...));
}
```

To retrieve the text of an element, use [`Text`](https://serenity-js.org/modules/protractor/class/src/screenplay/questions/text/Text.ts%7EText.html)

```js
import { Target, Text } from '@serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protractor';

class CustomerCreatePage {
    static customerCode = () =>
        Target.the('customer code').located(by.xpath(...));

    static customerCodeText = () =>
        Text.of(CustomerCreatePage.customerCode())
}
```

To perform a `substring` operation, use [`Question.map`](https://serenity-js.org/modules/core/class/src/screenplay/Question.ts%7EQuestion.html#instance-method-map):

```js
import { Target, Text } from '@serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protractor';

class CustomerCreatePage {
    static customerCode = () =>
        Target.the('customer code').located(by.xpath(...));

    static customerCodeText = () =>
        Text.of(CustomerCreatePage.customerCode())
            .map(actor => value => value.substring(15, 26));
}
```

To store the value so that it can be reused later, [`TakeNote`](https://serenity-js.org/modules/core/class/src/screenplay/interactions/TakeNote.ts%7ETakeNote.html) of it:

```js
import { actorCalled, TakeNotes, TakeNote, Note } from '@serenity-js/core';
import { BrowseTheWeb } from '@serenity-js/protractor';
import { protractor } from 'protractor';

actorCalled('Sudhir')
    .whoCan(
        BrowseTheWeb.using(protractor.browser),
        TakeNotes.usingAnEmptyNotepad(),
    )
    .attemptsTo(
        TakeNote.of(CustomerCreatePage.customerCodeText).as('customer code'),
        // do some other interesting things
        Enter.the(Note.of('customer code')).into(someField),
    )
```